# How can I switch from multiple disks to a single disk in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Because I ran out of space when shuffling, I was forced to add multiple disks on my Cassandra nodes.

When I finish compacting, cleaning up, and repairing, I'd like to remove them and return to one disk per node.

What is the procedure to make the switch?
Can I just kill cassandra, move the data from one disk to the other, remove the configuration for the second disk, and re-start cassandra?

I assume files will not have the same name and thus not be overwritten, is this the case?

Answer (score 2):

- Run **disablegossip** and **disablethrift** from nodetool, such that this
  node is seen as DOWN by other nodes.
- flush/**drain** the memtables, run compaction to merge SSTables, if any
- [optionally, take snapshot as a precaution]
- This stops all the other nodes/clients from writing to this node and since memtables are flushed to disk
- stop Cassandra (though this node is down, cluster is available for
  write/read, so zero downtime)
- move data/log contents from other disk to the disk you want
- make changes in cassandra.yaml to change the below paths:
      **commitlog_directory
      saved_caches_directory
      data_file_directories
      log_directory**
- restart cassandra

do this for all nodes.

Comment: Assuming I have enough space left to copy everything as is, is it necessary to run flush/drain/compaction? Can't I just stop cassandra, copy, and start? (my RF can handle 1 node down)